# Unable to load asset: Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription'

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout

i am receiving this error only from iphone ios 14 devices

> Fatal Exception: FlutterError
> Unable to load asset: assets/images/settings_unselected_icon.png.. Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription'.

[image: screenshot from crashlytics]

My app is working great on any ios version except ios 14

here is my code

```
class FitnessAppHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FitnessAppHomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FitnessAppHomeScreenState createState() => _FitnessAppHomeScreenState();
}

class _FitnessAppHomeScreenState extends State<FitnessAppHomeScreen> {
  List<TabIconData> tabIconsList = TabIconData.tabIconsList;
  var _selectedTab = _SelectedTab.home;

  void _handleIndexChanged(int i) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedTab = _SelectedTab.values[i];
    });
  }

  Widget tabBody = Container(
    color: Colors.white,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    PrivacyScreen.instance.enable(
      iosOptions: const PrivacyIosOptions(
        enablePrivacy: true,
        privacyImageName: "LaunchImage",
        autoLockAfterSeconds: 1,
        lockTrigger: IosLockTrigger.didEnterBackground,
      ),
      androidOptions: const PrivacyAndroidOptions(
        enableSecure: true,
        autoLockAfterSeconds: 1,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.11),
      blurEffect: PrivacyBlurEffect.dark,
    );
    for (final tab in tabIconsList) {
      tab.isSelected = false;
    }
    tabIconsList[0].isSelected = true;

    tabBody = const CustomizedView();
    dataStore.setSessions('currentSession', 0);
    incrementUserSession();
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      requestAttributionDetails();
    }

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
      if (dataStore.getSettings('pin').isEmpty) {
        PrivacyScreen.instance.pauseLock();
      } else {
        PrivacyScreen.instance.resumeLock();
        PrivacyScreen.instance.unlock();
        PrivacyScreen.instance.lock();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> requestAttributionDetails() async {
    String? token;

    try {
      token = await FlutterAsaAttribution.instance.attributionToken();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(token);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            final currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
              currentFocus.unfocus();
            }
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              tabBody,
              Column(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(),
                  ),
                  DotNavigationBar(
                    paddingR: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, top: 5),
                    marginR: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 35, vertical: 15),
                    // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    currentIndex: _SelectedTab.values.indexOf(_selectedTab),
                    dotIndicatorColor: Colors.white,
                    selectedItemColor: const Color(0xFF2EBDD8),
                    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    enableFloatingNavBar: true,
                    enablePaddingAnimation: false,
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(1, 1),
                          color: Colors.black12,
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0)
                    ],

                    onTap: (index) {
                      _handleIndexChanged(index);
                      if (index == 0) {
                        if (!mounted) {
                          return;
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          tabBody = const CustomizedView();
                        });
                      } else if (index == 1) {
                        if (!mounted) {
                          return;
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          tabBody = const GenerateCodeScreen();
                        });
                      } else if (index == 2) {
                        if (!mounted) {
                          return;
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          tabBody = const HistoryPage();
                        });
                      } else if (index == 3) {
                        if (!mounted) {
                          return;
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          tabBody = const SettingsPage();
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    items: [
                     
                      DotNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/scanner_unselected_icon.png',
                            scale: 1.9,
                            color: _selectedTab.index == 0
                                ? const Color(0xFF2EBDD8)
                                : null),
                        selectedColor: const Color(0xFF2EBDD8),
                      ),

                      
                      DotNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/generate_unselected_icon.png',
                            scale: 1.9,
                            color: _selectedTab.index == 1
                                ? const Color(0xFF2EBDD8)
                                : null),
                        selectedColor: const Color(0xFF2EBDD8),
                      ),

                     
                      DotNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/history_unselected.png',
                            scale: 1.9,
                            color: _selectedTab.index == 2
                                ? const Color(0xFF2EBDD8)
                                : null),
                        selectedColor: const Color(0xFF2EBDD8),
                      ),

                      
                      DotNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/settings_unselected_icon.png',
                            scale: 1.9,
                            color: _selectedTab.index == 3
                                ? const Color(0xFF2EBDD8)
                                : null),
                        selectedColor: const Color(0xFF2EBDD8),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

here is my pubspecs.yaml

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the images in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true


  assets:
    - assets/images/calender_icon.png
    - assets/images/call.png
    - assets/images/barcode.png
    - assets/images/clipboard_icon.png
    - assets/images/clipboard_icon.png
    - assets/images/contacts_icon.png
    - assets/images/email.png
    - assets/images/email_icon.png
    - assets/images/fb.png
    - assets/images/fb-white.png
    - assets/images/gallery_icon.png
    - assets/images/photo.png
    - assets/images/generate_selected_icon.png
    - assets/images/generate_unselected_icon.png
    - assets/images/history_selected.png
    - assets/images/history_unselected.png
    - assets/images/rateus.png
    - assets/images/rateus_circle.png
    - assets/images/rateus_star.png
    - assets/images/ig.png
    - assets/images/ig-white.png
    - assets/images/sc.png
    - assets/images/sc1.png
    - assets/images/sc1-white.png
    - assets/images/messages_icon.png
    - assets/images/phone_icon.png
    - assets/images/scanner_selected_icon.png
    - assets/images/scanner_unselected_icon.png
    - assets/images/speech-bubble.png
    - assets/images/spotify_icon.png
    - assets/images/spotify_icon-white.png
    - assets/images/settings_selected_icon.png
    - assets/images/settings_unselected_icon.png
    - assets/images/telegram.png
    - assets/images/text_icon.png
    - assets/images/tg.png
    - assets/images/tg-white.png
    - assets/images/tool_img.png
    - assets/images/transparent.png
    - assets/images/twitter_icon.png
    - assets/images/twitter_icon-white.png
    - assets/images/url_icon.png
    - assets/images/viber.png
    - assets/images/viber-white.png
    - assets/images/video_on.png
    - assets/images/video_off.png
    - assets/images/whatsapp.png
    - assets/images/whatsapp-white.png
    - assets/images/wifi_icon.png
    - assets/images/girl.png
    - assets/images/group_dots.png
    - assets/images/intro_1.png
    - assets/images/intro_2.png
    - assets/images/red_dot.png
    - assets/images/white_dot.png
    - assets/images/next_icon.png
    - assets/images/scan_icon.png
    - assets/images/idfa_allow.png
    - assets/images/heart.png
    - assets/images/analytics.png
    - assets/images/success.png
    - assets/sound/scan_beep.mp3
    - assets/svg/google.svg
    - assets/svg/ebay.svg
    - assets/svg/amazon.svg
    - assets/svg/transparent.svg
    - assets/svg/google_shopping.svg
    - assets/svg/google-shopping-logo.png
    - assets/svg/openfoodfacts.svg


  fonts:
    - family: SFPRO
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/sfpro/SFProDisplay-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/sfpro/SFProDisplay-Medium.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/sfpro/SFProDisplay-Semibold.ttf
          weight: 500
```

i have tried some people suggestion to clean up my flutter project like these steps, but with no success at all

> Quick Clean Cache
>
> Open android studio Tools->Flutter->Clean.
> Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.
> Or open terminal run "flutter clean"
> Remove pubspec.lock.

Comment: UPDATE: i was able to fix this error, the error caused as i am adding Adservice lib to ios devices below 14.5 so i have had to change it from required to optional

Answer (score 0):

try to comment out your assets and change it to this, then rebuild your app:

assets:

- assets/images/
- assets/svg/

Comment: i was using this before someone recommend me to with the image full path

Comment: its tedious and redundant to write all the path.  Once you say `assets/images/` then it tracks all the files inside your images directory so you dont need to write all the path manually. its error prone.